# Converting DateTime Columns in a DataGridView to Local TimeZone

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datetime, timezone

I have a C# Form Application that has a datagridview that displays Appointment Start Times and Appointment End Times among other things. I get all the data from a MySQL Database that stores the times in UTC, I want to convert those UTC times to the local time zone of the computer I have tried the code below and it does not appear to be working can anyone give me some advice on how to convert the times to local time zone.

```
 private void AppointmentsDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is DateTime)
        {
            e.Value = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)e.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            e.Value = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)e.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of e.Value when you debug this method? Your code seems correct, and should give you the local date and time. Is is possible that the e.Value is already converted to local date time?

Comment: how can I check e.Value? I apologize I just do not know how to check.

Comment: Do you know how to debug? Put a break point on the `if()` line with F9 while your cursor is on this line, and just press F5

Comment: okay I have the first Date time value in e.value it is {6/1/2020 3:20:00 PM} how can I check what time zone it is set to?

Comment: check `(e.Value as DateTime).Kind`

Comment: You say the code is not working. What does not working mean in your case? Are the dates incorrect? How do you know they are incorrect? What is the expected output and what is the actual output which you interpret as "incorrect"

Comment: The Times are still being displayed in UTC even after this section of code is run and I need it to be displayed in the Local time zone of the computer and It is not working that is what I mean by incorrect.

Comment: In My case I am in CST but If I change my time zone on my computer I want the times to adjust to whatever timezone I change my computer to.

Comment: So you want this value `{6/1/2020 3:20:00 PM}` to be displayed as `{6/1/2020 10:20:00 PM}` and it is not?

Comment: What is the value of `(e.Value as DateTime).Kind`

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: @DathonWeber - Some resource that will help you learn how to debug your code: [*How to debug for absolute beginners*](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-absolute-beginners), [*Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio*](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger)

Comment: Thank you. @MattJohnson-Pint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine as it is, but could probably be simplified using [`DateTime.ToLocalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime)

```
if (e.Value is DateTime)
{
    e.Value = ((DateTime) e.Value).ToLocalTime();
}
```

If you're using C# 7.0 or newer, you can make it even cleaner using [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is).

```
if (e.Value is DateTime dt)
{
    e.Value = dt.ToLocalTime();
}
```

It's not necessary to use `SpecifyKind` in advance, unless for some reason the value *already* has `DateTimeKind.Local` incorrectly assigned to its `.Kind` property.  If it does, I'd suggest fixing that wherever it's created, not in the UI.